# batch script SSRS file backups

Tags: batch-file, reporting-services

I had created a text file with the SSRS file backup Microsoft says to backup. I was using a batch file to locate all the files in the directory structure.

Using the following commands

```
for /F %G in (C:\file.txt) dp dir /s /b %G >> c:\filepath.txt
```

It write the correct path out to the file but when I try to do a copy to another location I make the same path to a directory structure of my choice.

```
for /F %G in (C:\filepath.txt) do md "C:\Users\Location\Desktop\SSRS Migration Backup\FileBack%~pG"
```

After making the directory I would copy the file with this command.

```
for /F %G in (C:\filepath.txt) do copy "%G" "C:\Users\Location\Desktop\SSRS Migration Backup\FileBack%~pG"
```

The file path for C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\"

Will in the `%G` parameter pass as "\" Only

I have tried forcing the parameter to `%~fG` it will only show "\Programs"

I even have tried `@echo` the `%G` parameter and it only displays on screen "\" why will the path to the file not pass correct?

Comment: Use `%%G` in batch files and `%G` on command line.

Comment: I already know that is why I'm using this at the command line first. That still doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested here is a powershell way I came up with to do the same thing to help backup your files.

```html
<#
created by:    wolfsvein 
created date:  03/19/2018
Notes:         Script is created to backup existing file paths from reading a input file you create.
               Insert a list of files with extensions in a flat text file. The file then loads the file.ext
               to a variable array and then loops through created the directory structure then copying to the file backup
               destination.


               Flat Text File Example (No header in the file this will cause script to error.)

               filename.exe
               filename.config
               filename.xlsx               
#>

# Create File Path Structure
$FileName = Get-Content c:\file.txt

# Create File Backup Destination
$FileDestination = "C:\CopyToLocation\SSRS Migration Backup\FileBackUp"

#Loop through each file name to create directory structure then copy files to backup location on server.
foreach ($File in $FileName) 
    {
        $FilePaths = 
            (
                Get-ChildItem "c:\" -filter $File -recurse -Erroraction 'silentlycontinue' |
                Select-Object -ExpandProperty directory  |
                Split-Path -NoQualifier
            )
            <#
            $FilePaths = $FilePaths.replace("}","") #This is only here if Select-Object -ExpandProperty is 
                                                    not in place it will leave "}" on end of file path and cause an error.
            #>

            foreach ($FilePath in $FilePaths) 
                {
                if(-not (Test-Path "$FileDestination$FilePath")) 
                    {New-Item -path $FileDestination -name "$FilePath" -type Directory}
                $FileExists = "$FileDestination$FilePath\$file"
                if(-not (test-path "$FileExists"))
                    {Copy-Item -Path "c:$FilePath\$File" -Destination "$FileExists"}
                }
    } 
 
 #EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit hard to follow.. Try adding "delims=" to the for command.

```
for /F "delims=" %G in (C:\filepath.txt) do copy "%G" "C:\Users\Location\Desktop\SSRS Migration Backup\FileBack%~pG"
```

Comment: Delims is for delimiter each line has the file path to the file location the problem is the windows %Program Files% directory passed into the local varible from the read file instead of passing the fully qualified path it just pass "\" and nothing else.

Comment: This did work my understanding of the delims was off